# Mysql insert with Python Could not Process Parameters

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm working on a function in python that reads values from MySql. When I insert using the same format there are no errors but when I select it gives me the error
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(555),
it must be of type list, tuple or dict
Here is my code that is giving the error

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM LIBS')
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in result:
                user_id = row[0]
                song_id = row[1]
                if(user_id == userno):
                    cursor.execute("SELECT s_title FROM SONG WHERE s_id = (%s)", (song_id))
                    print(row[1])
```

What I don't understand is when I use the exact same format for INSERT with (%s) there are no errors

I tried adding a comma inside the song_id and then running them as                     cursor.execute("SELECT s_title FROM SONG WHERE s_id = (%s)", (song_id,))
but I got the error mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found.

Comment: I added a second duplicate link to explain the "Unread result found" error message.

Answer (score 0):

`params` must be a list, tuple or dict (see [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html))

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT s_title FROM SONG WHERE s_id = (%s)", (song_id,))
```

Note the comma after `song_id`. Without the comma, it's just a `str` and not a `tuple`. This is only necessary for creating tuples with one element.

Comment: Doing it like that gives me error unread result found

Comment: Yeah, that's because you are not using the cursor properly.  You are executing a statement, but do not consume the result before executing another statement.  You can set `buffered=True` when creating the cursor.